# A star search extremely slow with python

Tags: python, a-star

here is some code I wrote for an A* pathfinding algorithm. However as soon as I make the start and end nodes slightly far away, the program takes minutes to run. Why is this? The code below ran in 2 minutes yet the start and end node are so close. Thanks for the help. I feel like it has to do with the part of getting the lowest f value in the open list, however I am not sure.

```
import cProfile

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, position = None):
        self.position = position
        self.parent = parent
        self.g = 0
        self.h = 0
        self.f = 0

    def euclidean_distance(self, x_end, y_end):
        return math.sqrt(abs(self.position[0]-x_end)**2 + abs(self.position[1]-y_end)**2)

    def pos(self):
        return self.position



maze =  [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

def astar():

    openlist = []
    closed = []

    current = Node(None,[0,0])
    destination = [4,8]
    openlist.append(current)

    adjacent = [[1,0],[0,1],[-1,0],[0,-1]]

    while len(openlist) > 0:
        cur_index = 0
        for index in range(len(openlist)):
            if openlist[index].f < openlist[cur_index].f:
                cur_index = index
        
        current = openlist[cur_index]
        openlist.pop(cur_index)
        closed.append(current)

        if current.pos() == destination:
            print("ok")
            path = []
            current_node = current
            while current_node is not None:
                path.append(current_node.position)
                current_node = current_node.parent
            return path

        for candidate in adjacent:
            x = candidate[0]+current.pos()[0]
            y = candidate[1]+current.pos()[1]
            if x > (len(maze) - 1) or x < 0 or y > (len(maze[len(maze)-1])-1) or y < 0:
                continue
            if maze[x][y] != 0:
                continue
            next = Node(current,[x,y])
            neighbour = next
            if neighbour not in closed:
                temp = current.g + 1
                if neighbour in openlist:
                    if neighbour.g > temp:
                        neighbour.g = temp
                else:
                    neighbour.g = temp
                    openlist.append(neighbour)

            neighbour.h = math.sqrt(abs(neighbour.pos()[0]-destination[0])**2 + abs(neighbour.pos()[1]-destination[1])**2)
            neighbour.f = neighbour.g + neighbour.h
            
            # for val in openlist:
            #     if neighbour == val and neighbour.g > val.g:
            #         continue
            # openlist.append(neighbour)

cProfile.run('astar()')
path = astar()

new = []
for r in range(len(maze)):
    temp = []
    for g in range(len(maze[r])):
        if maze[r][g] == 1:
            temp.append("#")
        elif [r,g] in path:
            temp.append("^")
        else:
            temp.append(".")
    new.append(temp)
    print(" ".join(temp))
```